# Little o-Notation

Tags: real-analysis

I need to show that $x=o(x^2\sin^2(x))$ for $x \to +\infty$

my approach is following: I examined if $\frac{x}{{x^2\sin^2(x)}}$ as $x \rightarrow +\infty$

since the therm above simplyfies to $\frac{1}{{x\sin^2(x)}}$ and $\sin^2(x) \leq 1$ $\forall x$

and $\lim_{{x \to +\infty}} x\sin^2(x)=+\infty$ $\implies$ $\frac{1}{{x\sin^2(x)}} = 0$

is the proof correct this way?

Comment: It's not true.  For example, $|x^2 \sin^2(x)| < |x|$ when $x$ is near a multiple of $\pi$.

Comment: but does it hold for values of $x$ when $x$ approaches $\infty$

Comment: Yes, there are arbitrarily large multiples of $\pi$.

Comment: @Asddbass $x\sin^2(x)=0$, for $x=\pi,2\pi,3\pi,4\pi,\ldots$ and this sequence approaches infinity.

Answer (score 2):

The statement $f(x)\to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$ requires that the function has an arbitrarily large lower bound *everywhere* in some interval $(c,\infty)$. For $f(x)=x\sin^2(x)$, the only valid lower bound in such an interval is $0$.

Another way to look at it is that the limit exists only if every sequence $f(x_n)$, $n=1,2,\ldots$ where $x_n \to \infty$ converges and has the same limit (finite or otherwise). For $f(x)=x^2\sin^2(x)$, you're probably thinking that there is a sequence $x_n$ such that $f(x_n)\to \infty$, and you would be right. But you can see also that the sequence $x_n=n\pi$ generates the sequence $f(x_n)=0,0,0,\cdots \to 0$ which is what Robert is saying in the comment. In fact, for every positive real number $L$, the solution set of $x^2\sin^2(x)=L$ is countably infinite and has no largest element.

The statement $x^2\sin^2(x)\to\infty$ is false, it's simply inconsistent with the definition of a limit.